# Dynamic web page with no reloading

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, meteor

I've just recently discovered slack.com and I fell in love with the way they handle their interface. If you've never used it before it's quite easy:

There is a side navbar and an main container on the right. Everytime you click an item in the side navbar it's content is loaded in the container. The focused item changes, the container's content changes, but the page doesn't reload.

If the data changes in the meantime it is magically updated.

What would it take to achieve something like that?

1. URL changing, page not reloading
2. Content always up to date

I've been looking at meteorjs in the past few days but the url part is never mentionned.

Comment: Part 2 is really too broad. The URL changing bit is done with [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

Comment: The concept you are talking about is single page application SPA.  http://www.johnpapa.net/spa/ this url is really good to know about what exactly single page application means. AngularJs is awesome frontend mv* framework using which you can build something  like slack.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the "url changing feature but no reload", I think @Kavan Pancholi answered your question. Another way to achieve that is by using the yield templates feature of iron-router.

You are using meteor, it means that you *can* do it without too much trouble (forget about Ajax & Sockets).

I don't know Slack (but I'll definitely have a look at it) but from what I understand, all data is preloaded/lazy loaded and they only change the displayed elements. In other terms, you keep ready and loaded all your client subscriptions or you bring them up when your yield template is loaded.

I will have a look at Slack and edit this if I realize I did not understood correctly what you are aiming for.

**Edit** Ok I tried it. You need to use yield templates with iron-router and they also added some transitions effect you can achieve with [_uihooks](http://www.webtempest.com/meteorjs-animation) + a loading template

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Slack is awesome. We (My team) use it everyday. I use it so regularly, at some point I don't check email but I check slack.

So, up to your question.

1. URL changing, page not reloading

It can be easily done by javascript [ Tl;dr ]

Code:

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
```

2. Content always up to date

Well this can be done in two way,
i.  via Ajax and Javascript
ii. via socket

i.  via Ajax and Javascript:
in javascript you can make setTimeout function to fire ajax request in some duration. via Ajax it will get newest message from backend and it will be shown.

ii. via socket:
in socket, in your case if you use node.js there is a very popular library named [socket.io](http://socket.io) which will get and update message in real time.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You need Ajax. You can use it in conjunction with a script, probably PHP that checks the state of the databse over a timer interval (a "heartbeat") and if anything has changed you load in the new data. I'd recommend having a specific column for a datetimestamp to compare with to make the smallest possible load on your database from this as a lot of users being on the page at the same time will make a lot of requests.

Answer (score 0):

On top of that, if you use a framework like angular, you'll notice urls like this:

> http://localhost:3000/#/chat/room

You've probably seen similar with wikipedia in having urls like this:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat#Cats_and_humans

That little `#` won't reload the page on the url, so you can use that to make a url routing action without changing the page. You can access it with `window.location.hash`. So on the wikipedia article, you'd get

```
> window.location.hash
#Cats_and_humans
```

Combine that with ajax and event listeners and you can do something similar.

```
// using jquery

// set a callback when the hash changes
$(window).on('hashchange', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var hash = window.location.hash;

  // get your container where you want to add data and clear it out
  var $container = $('#container');
  $container.html('<ul></ul>');

  if (hash === '#/movies') {
    // request json from an endpoint, and with the data, append it to the dom
    $.getJSON('/api/movies', function (data) {
      data.each(function (el) {
        $container.append('<li>' + el.name + '</li>');
      });
    });
  }
});
```